# How to call method from template in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have my vue instance:

```
var testOptions = new Vue({
    el: '#testOptions',
    methods: {
        getURL: function () {
            return (window.location.href);
        },
        testOne: function () {
            console.log('!!');
        },
        testTwo: function () {
            console.log('!!!!');
        }
    },
    data: {
        shares: [
            { text: 'testOne', icon: 'ico_test1.svg',func: testOne() },
            { text: 'testTwo', icon: 'ico_test2.svg', func: testTwo() },
        ]
    }
});
```

Is it possible to call my method `testOne`/`testTwo` which I pass to `shares` array like this:

```
<li v-on:click="share.func" class="test-options__option">
    {{share.text}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Instead of calling the function inside each share, just pass the reference to it.
You need to use `this.` as those are instance functions.

```
shares: [
    { text: 'testOne' icon: 'ico_test1.svg', func: this.testOne },
    { text: 'testTwo' icon: 'ico_test2.svg', func: this.testTwo },
]
```

Also, `data` property should be a **Function** that returns object (the actual data) and it's a good practice to add that property onto the top of your Vue component.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vnef5d4c/11/

Comment: didn't you update your code in some way? any errors it's throwing? Also, the `data` property should be a function if it's not the main component, but in your case that's not a problem, if the code is the same as you shared.

Comment: when I click on `li` I am not getting any errors but on page load I got error : `Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined`. In Vue Devtools I see that reference to my methods are equal to undefined for each `li`

Comment: That's probably because data is not a function. Try changing those `data` property to function that returns data object. `data: function () { return { /* data */ } } `

Comment: When `data` property is not a function `this` is not pointing on the Vue instance but the different scope instead. You should write `data` as a function most of the times.